# why the last Value Row values are repeated for the HTML Table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a static Html Table which contains one button "Add" and when  clicking on that button it creates a new row which contains some text boxes 
and it append to this table .But my Problem is say i have 3 rows and when i click "Add" we are able to create the new ROW  but the Previous row values 
are copied in to new row that is being generated  .Here is the Function That iam using

```
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        tr= $("#Tbl tr:last").html();
        num= $('#num').val()*1;
        first= $("#Tbl tr:last").attr('id').substr(4)*1;
        last=first+num;
        for(i=first+1;i<=last;i++) {
            var newtr= tr.replace(first,i);
            $('#Tbl').append('<tr id="txt_'+i+'">'+newtr+'</tr>');
        }   
    });
```

How do i make the  value Selected as  "ABC" in Select box  when the new Row is being added.Iam using this statement But did not workout .How can i make the value as selected

```
$('#Tbl tr:last :input').find('input[name="code"]').val('ABC');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Patrick points out, you may be copying in values from the last row.  So why not clear them out after you create the new row?  Do this after the for loop:

```
$('#Tbl tr:last :input').val('');
```

This should select the input fields in the last tr of the #Tbl table and remove values from them.  This will specifically select the last row, but now I see that you're adding a variable number of rows, so lets handle that properly.

Since you're appending a bunch of rows, why not clean them up as you add them?

```
for(i=first+1;i<=last;i++) {
    var newtr= tr.replace(first,i);
    $('#Tbl').append('<tr id="txt_'+i+'">'+newtr+'</tr>').find(':input').val('');
}
```

That should handle as many rows as you can add.

Comment: @Surreal:Say If i add 10 rows  to the Table than it is emptying the Last row input value only and the rest 9 rows seesm to be same

Comment: That's right - I only wrote it to do so.  Now that I review your code again, I see that you're adding `num` rows.  I think I can work with that.

Comment: OK, try that on - clear inputs as you add the row.  Much simpler, too.

Comment: @SurealDreams:Would That be applicable to the Select Elements also

Comment: @Someone: Yes - it will clear text, textarea and select inputs.

Comment: @SurealDreams:With the The above edit it is also removing all the Values in the inputs of previously entered values

Comment: @Someone: No - it should only clear out the new rows as they are appended.  It won't touch any of the existing table.

Comment: @Surreal:It is clearing existing inputs .That we handled using the forst statement writeen .But Hoe do i remove the Select Element

Comment: @Someone: If you just want to clear text inputs, then use :text instead of :input

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a real jQuery hero, but why not use simply this?

```
$('#Tbl tr:last').after('<tr>...</tr>')
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me that when you do

```
tr= $("#Tbl tr:last").html();
```

your grabbing all of the html from inside that previous row (including the values of any controls inside that row) and pasting it into the new row

Answer (score 0):

When you type into a text box, it sets the "value" attribute in the HTML. So later, when you copy the innerHTML of the previous row, it takes those "value" attributes and duplicates them in your new row.

Instead of parsing the HTML of the previous row, you might want want to keep your data within your script and use that to generate new rows.

```
var nextId = 0;
var DEFAULT_ROW_HTML = "<tr id=\"@ID@\"><td><input type=\"text\" /></td>...</tr>";
...
$("#Tbl").append(DEFAULT_ROW_HTML.replace("@ID@", nextId));
```

Know what I mean, jelly bean?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#Tbl').each(function(){
        var $table = $(this);
        // Number of td's in the last table row
        var n = $('tr:last td', this).length;
        var tds = '<tr>';
        for(var i = 0; i < n; i++){
            tds += '<td> </td>';
        }
        tds += '</tr>';
        if($('tbody', this).length > 0){
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        }else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});
```